# Chrome last session - Force refresh tabs

Tags: google-chrome

I use Chrome as a daily-basis browser. When I close my browser I prefer it to "continue last session", so, when I open it, my already open tabs are there and that's great.

The problem here is that Chrome saves the "session" and when I start Chrome it will load outdated content tabs instead of the fresh ones.

This is good for some occasions but for my personal use is bad (e.g. for Superuser I want the updated content on).

**How can I force Chrome to refresh the content of my tabs when I open it?**

Comment: Same problem as mine? - [Google Chrome “Continue where you left off” does not continue where I left](https://superuser.com/questions/1314748/google-chrome-continue-where-you-left-off-does-not-continue-where-i-left)

Comment: @arieljannai I don't guess so. When I open Chrome my tabs are correct. I just wanna those tabs to refresh to get a current-time information.

Comment: Three things that it's worth checking - `1)` This issue still occur if you disable all extensions, apps and background apps? `2)` From a newly created Chrome Profile? `3)` Try disabling the `hardware acceleration` (under advanced settings).

Comment: @arieljannai 1) Yeah, I also use several other computers (without login) and it seems a global setting; 2) Yes, see 1); 3) I tried but no effect

Comment: Others computers? It sounds really weird. Others computers that you're logged in to? Just others? What version of Chrome do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Chrome extension
[Reload all tabs](https://github.com/mohamedmansour/reload-all-tabs-extension)
reloads or refreshes all tabs, with
a quick keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) which can be customized.

The extension
[Awesome Reload All Tabs Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-reload-all-tabs-b/kamfkajbgmjkfmfgcikbmbmpjfokfijk)
adds a button that can be used to
reload all tabs in the current Chrome window (or all Chrome windows).

Comment: This suits my needs (although with extensions but I'm fine with it). If anything more doesn't come out I'll pick this one.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically do this on startup? So without to need to click a button or keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Jan: Startup of what?

Comment: Startup of Chrome

Comment: @Jan: This is a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option of hitting `F5` when you open chrome.  This is the default `Refresh` for a given tab.  Unfortunately, you would have to hit `F5` for every tab that opens when you open chrome.

Comment: That is what I already do..